# Way to pass exception and raise error if no exception returned

Tags: python, pygsheets

```
def create_spreadsheet_with_api(connection, filename):
    try:
       connection.open(filename)
       if (no exception):
           raise exception file already exists
       if (there exception):
           connection.create(filename)
```

Using pygsheets library which uses google api, I'm trying to create spreadsheet with given name, if it's not already exists.

I receive Exception pygsheets.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound:

So I need something like reverse Exception, or if there are better practice of doing it in python your advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `try` clause has an `else` part, which is executed if no exception is raised (similarly named, but totally unrelated to the well known `if-else`). So

```
def create_spreadsheet_with_api(connection, filename):
    try:
        connection.open(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        connection.create(filename)
    else:
        raise FileAlreadyExistsError
```